# Android: Right to left tiled drawable

Tags: android, xml, imageview, drawable

How can I make a drawable that consist of two drawables: one repeats on y-axis and other "finishes" it on the right end?

In my app I use it like this:

```
<bitmap  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:src="@drawable/logo_pattern_file"
     android:tileMode="repeat"
     android:antialias="true"
     android:dither="false"
     android:filter="false">
 </bitmap>
```

And next to it stands ImageView with the "end part". The problem is, tiling part draws form left to right and "crops" not on the right place, messing up the whole logo.

Here's what I am getting:

(New users are not allowed to post images, here's a link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQWFt.jpg)

How should I make it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rotated pattern]

It's possible to accomplish this by rotating a repeating bitmap (left side to right and vice versa) by nesting it into `rotate` tag, just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" >

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/core"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />

</rotate>
```

Your layout could be sth like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/repeat_core" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="95px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/end" />

</LinearLayout>
```